Google Voice but with Line Breaks
I am trying to use Google App Script to send an email to my google voice which then sends a text to my phone. Everything works flawlessly, except that I cannot get line breaks to work. (also, to be clear, even direct from my gmail fails to produce line breaks)
NOTE: I know there are other ways to send text messages programmatically, but one of the requirements is that they get to my phone in the same chat. If I use my carrier's email to text abilities, it comes from a different contact each time.

##Quick Breakdown of What I Have Tried:##

\n \r \r\n \n are all completely ignored
\n\n ends the message at this point, ignoring all subsequent
text
%0a and %0A just present as text
<br> present as text

if I encode as {htmlBody: message}:

<br> are ignored
<br><br> ends the message at this point, ignoring all subsequent
text

I have also tried all of the above with temperate literals and simply line breaking my code inside temperate literals

##Code Examples##
Here is how the chat bots and other questions on stackoverflow say it should work:
function sendSMS() {
  var phoneNumber = '1234567890@txt.voice.google.com';
  var subject = '';
  var message = 'Hello,\nThis is a test message with line breaks.\nPlease confirm if it works.\n\nThank you.';
  
  GmailApp.sendEmail(phoneNumber, subject, message);
}

With htmlBody
function sendSMS() {
  var phoneNumber = '1234567890@txt.voice.google.com';
  var subject = '';
  var message = 'Hello,<br>This is a test message with line breaks.<br>Please confirm if it works.<br><br>Thank you.';

  GmailApp.sendEmail(phoneNumber, subject, '', {
    htmlBody: message
  });
}


Questions

Is there a way to do what I am trying to do in the way that I am trying to do this?

Is there a different way / third party API that can achieve the results I am looking for while maintaining a single 'from' contact in my text messages?


